# Schema migration of ids and n to m relationships in objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

If have a User entity which previously had a String id. I'd like to migrate to a Long id which seems simple:

```
public class UserEntity  {
   /*@Id*/
   @Index String oldId;
   @Id Long newId;
  /* other indexed fields I use for loading the entity */

  private List<Ref<ReferencedEntity>> collections;
}

public class ReferencedEntity {
   private List<Ref<User>> owners;
}
```

Since I load the user via different fields I can check if the user has a null `newId` and if so just null the old one save it back so the auto generator will set a new Id in the `newId` field.

The problem is now my n to m relationship to other entities. How should I migrate those? I have a `Ref` on both sides so I guess I just can load the refs on the user entity side and replace the other side with the new Id.

The general question is how to migrate n to m relationship if one side needs a new id?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably thinking with a relational database strategy. When you update a value on one side, the other side will not be updated, therefore you have to update both entities. Since this is NoSql you have to think differently.

I would take this strategy.

First load the "old" user entity and save it again in the new structure. Once you have confirmed that all the data you loaded has been converted to the new object (I suggest using BigQuery), then you should spawn a task for each referenced entity using the indexed oldId and update the reference of the owners in the ReferencedEntity.

It will take a while to load but it is probably a safe way to do it.